# what are port need to enable in firewall for mailbox migration?

Tags: office365, exchange-2010

what are the ports is required to do the mailbox migration in On-premises to O365?
what are the ports are required  to do the mailbox migration in O365 -O365?

Answer (score 1):

That may depend on the type of the On-premises installation.

In general, these ports are required for Office 365 according to your needs :

- TCP 443 - ADFS, Microsoft Online Portal (Website), Outlook 2010, Outlook 2007,
  Outlook Web Access (Website), SharePoint Online (Website), Lync 2010 client,
  CRLs (Certificate Revocation Lists) to verify SSL
- TCP 25 - SMTP Mail routing
- TCP 587 - SMTP relay
- TCP 143/993 - IMAP migration tool
- TCP 995 - POP3
- TCP 80 and 443 - Online services directory, simple exchange migration tool, simple IMAP migration
- STUN/UDP 3478 - Lync Online (outbound audio and video session)
- RTC/UDP 50000-59999 - Lync Online (outbound audio and video session)
- TCP 50040-50059 - App sharing and file transfer
- STUN/TCP 443 - Lync Online (outbound audio, video, and app sharing session)
- TCP 443 - Lync (Data sharing sessions)
- TCP 5223 - Lync Mobile Push iOS only
- TCP/UDP 5671 - when using Azure Service Bus
- TCP 6001, 6002, 6004 - when migrating from Exchange 2003